# What determines Authentication for a folder in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-8

I have a folder under a web site that causes a request for authentication whenever I try and access it or any of its sub-folders. In IIS, 'Authentication' only has Anonymous enabled, and '.NET Authorization Rules' is set to 'Allow all Users'.

What could make IIS request authorization when I try and access this folder? Is there anything in the web app that could cause authorization to be requested?

This is IIS 8 under Windows 8. The application was developed under Windows 7 and transferred to Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous Authentication uses an identity to access files on disk. You can check what identity by right-clicking Anonymous Authentication in IIS and selecting Edit... It is probably using IUSR (that is the default).

[image: Anonymous Authentication settings in IIS]

You have 3 options:

1. Give the IUSR account or the IIS_IUSRS group permission to access the folder
2. Set a different specific user that has access
3. Set Anonymous Authentication to use the application pool identity, then grant this (virtual) account permissions to access the folder

Comment: IUSR is the configured account, but IIS_IUSRS has full control on the folder. But thanks for a valuable lesson.